# Reset password with nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to build a reset password functionality.

the code seems to be working fine, I am getting a success message when I test with postman. "Check your mail for a Password reset link."

But I am not receiving any mail.

````
email = process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID;
pass = process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD;

exports.ResetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.email) {
    return res
    .status(500)
    .json({ message: 'Email is required' });
  }
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res
    .status(409)
    .json({ message: 'Email does not exist' });
  }
  var resettoken = new passwordResetToken({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });

  resettoken.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
    passwordResetToken.find({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: { $ne: resettoken.resettoken } }).remove().exec();
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Check your mail for a Password reset link.' });
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: process.env.MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER || 'Gmail',
      port: 465,
      auth: {
        user: email,
        pass: pass
      }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      to: user.email,
      from: email,
      subject: 'Password Reset',
      text: 'You are receiving this email because you requested for a password reseet for your account.\n\n' +
      'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
      'http://localhost:4200/reset-password/' + resettoken.resettoken + '\n\n' +
      'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    })
  })
  }```
````

Comment: Which email service you are using ? If you are using your gmail account have you turned the SMTP on.

Comment: I am using Gmail. turns out that I didn't turn own on the less secure app button. Thanks.